# SSL https error on 404 pages, but other pages are working fine with redirection enabled

Tags: apache, ssl, https, url-rewriting, drupal-7

My drupal site has auto redirection to remove www prefix from URLs and add https as seen from these links, they goto a 404 page tat is just a contact page:

http://www.phonerepair.us/some_random_url-- redirection works 
http://phonerepair.us/some_random_url -- redirection works
https://www.phonerepair.us/some_random_url -- **redirection FAILS**

https://phonerepair.us/some_random_url -- This should be END RESULT

My apache .conf setting and .htaccess for this domain is:

[image]

What could be off in my redirection rules to cause the https://www to throw an SSL error like this:

[image]

Comment: `www.phonerepair.us` is different from `phonerepair.us` at least during certificate validation. Hence you need a certificate listing both names (or `phonerepair.us` plus the wildcard `*.phonerepair.us`), which is not the case for now, and this is what your browser tells you. You need to go back to your CA and request a new certificate covering both names. Also, in general, post configuration items as text, not as an image, and since this is not about programming, it is offtopic here. See [su], [sf] or [webmaster.se]

Answer (score 0):

Deleted the ServerAlias and then duplicated the entire virtualhost in my .conf file and just added www to the ServerName. Now there should be 2 virtualhost settings. One for the non-www domain and another for the www one. Then do a **service apache2 restart**

Delete the ssl-le.conf file for your domain.

Then I regenerated my SSL certs using **certbot --apache** and select both of these domains and generate.

Now my www and non-www works. Below is how my conf files look. A better approach is to use the * wildcard config, but I wasn't sure how to get that working with **certbot --apache** command

[image]